# How to set language (locale) inside a Route::group()... in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel, routes

Inside blade - `welcome.blade.php`.

```
 <div class="links">
      <a href="https://laravel.com/docs">{{ __('passwords.reset') }}</a>
 </div>
```

Inside `web.php`.

If I run:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

I get the correct welcome blade page with the correct translation.

Another Route:

```
Route::get('welcome/{lang}', function ($lang) {
//    echo $lang;
//    dd(Lang::getLocale());
    App::setLocale($lang);
    //dd(Lang::getLocale());
    return view('welcome');    
    //
});
```

If I run `dd(Lang::getLocale());` I can see the correct language sent by the URL `http://testapp/welcome/en`. In this case `'en'`. If I put `dd()` in comment I can see the correct translation in Laravel Welcome page.

But when I run this code:

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'welcome'], function (){    
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'{lang}'], function ($lang){
        //echo $lang;
        //dd(Lang::getLocale());
        App::setLocale($lang);
        //dd(Lang::getLocale());
        return view('welcome');            
    });
});
```

This is what I have:

**echo $lang;** gives me `ErrorException in web.php line 30: Object of class Illuminate\Routing\Router could not be converted to string`

**dd(Lang::getLocale());**  gives me `'en'`.

**App::setLocale($lang);** gives me 404 Not Found

**App::setLocale($lang);** AND **return view('welcome');** gives me 404 Not Found

**return view('welcome');** gives me 404 Not Found

And When I run

```
App::setLocale($lang);
dd(Lang::getLocale());
return view('welcome');
```

I get an object:

```
Router {#21 ▼
  #events: Dispatcher {#23 ▶}
  #container: Application {#3 ▶}
  #routes: RouteCollection {#25 ▶}
  #current: null
  #currentRequest: null
  #middleware: array:6 [▶]
  #middlewareGroups: array:2 [▶]
  +middlewarePriority: array:6 [▶]
  #binders: []
  #patterns: []
  #groupStack: array:3 [▶]
}
```

So, my guess is that `Route::group(['prefix'=>'{lang}'...` is returning a object not a string. This is why it crashes the process.

How can I solve this issue using `Route::group()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Route::group` is just a wrapper to organize and group other routes. It is not a defined url. `Route::group` and `Route::post/get` don't work that same, so you cannot put logic inside a `Route::group` call.

What you can do is the following

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'welcome'], function (){    
    Route::group(['prefix'=>'{lang}'], function (){
        Route::get('/', function ($lang) {
            App::setLocale($lang);
            return view('welcome');
        });            
     });
});
```