# Returning a controller in Laravel 5.6 route file

Tags: laravel

I am trying to route a request to a controller method. When I do this it works:

```
Route::get('/path', 'controller@method');
```

I would like to set the locale before calling the controller. I tried different options and nothing works:

```
Route::get('/path', function(){
   desired_function();
   return action('controller@method');
});
```

and

```
Route::get('/path', function(){
   desired_function();
   return [
    'uses' => 'controller@method'
    ];
});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43079433/how-to-set-language-locale-inside-a-routegroup-in-laravel-5-4

Comment: the mentioned question is about returning a view not a controller.

Comment: checkout middlewares docs:https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware

Comment: Why don't you set the locale inside the controller?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir because intially `App::setLocale()` did not work inside the controller. However, I tried `use App` and it actually worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create a `app/Http/Middleware/SetLocale.php` with content:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SetLocale
{

    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        \App::setLocale('en'); // or get it from request
        // or:
        // $request->attributes->set('locale', 'en'); 
        // in action: $request->get('locale');
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

2) Attach it to route:

```
Route::get('/path', 'controller@method')
       ->middleware('App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale');
```

or to route group:

```
Route::group([
  'middleware' => [
    'App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale'
  ]
], 
function() {

  Route::get('/path', 'controller@method');

});
```

if You want it to be used globally everywhere:

in `app/Http/Kernel.php` :

```
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    ... 
    'App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale' // add it to end of array
];
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. For my own knowledge, why can't I redirect to a controller?

Comment: What You mean under word: `redirect` ?

Comment: example that I wrote is preparing stuff before Your controller action being called. that's why it's called middleware. so why to redirect to controller if it's already being called after passing through middlewares?

Comment: correction: you need to add `use App` in the middleware file.

Comment: @Patriot see slash: `\App`  ;)

Comment: what I mean is why can't I return a controller in the route closure?

Comment: @Patriot You may, read docs: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/trigger-controllers-action?page=1  just interesting, why to write such code as Yours in routing when there are tons of elegant solutions? :)

Comment: In the setlocale.php file. `App::setLocale('en');' does not work. it only worked for me when I add use App at the top. Am I missing something?

Comment: how about using helper: `app()`

Comment: I already applied your solution and it worked, thanks. I am just curious why returning a controller method in routing does not work. Just for my knowledge.

Comment: I think when You return a controller action it uses factory to create controller instance and call it: `app()->make('App\Http\Controllers\SomeController'); return  app()->call([$controller, 'someAction'], $arguments);` that means it calls controller without passing through middlewares (action is being called with different context). But it's just a guess...